# Passing null values to the controller when I submit?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

After I run, when I type the value in Username textbox and clicked submit button. 
In Controller I check the object its showing null values.... If i remove the forloop and list its working...... give me a solution

Controller :

```
 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(LogonViewModel lvm)
        {
            LogonViewModel lv = new LogonViewModel();

            return View();
        }
```

Model:

```
 public class LogonViewModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "User Name is Required")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }
```

View

```
@model IList<clientval.Models.LogonViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>   
<script src="../../assets/js/val.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {  
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m[i].UserName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].UserName)
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(per => per[i].UserName)

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the `for` loop? What are trying to achieve? You only have one `LogonViewModel` in your controller action there is no need for the loop. As you mentioned it works without the loop, so that is the solution: remove the loop.

Comment: this is sample i have posted...but i am using in my project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your POST controller action must take a collection because that's what you have in your view:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(IList<LogonViewModel> lvm)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(sting[] firstname)
        {
            LogonViewModel lv = new LogonViewModel();

            return View();
        }    If I change the Controller to pass parameter instead of stated above. Its passing null values

Answer (score 1):

You are producing in your view - and submitting to server - *multiple* names. When you use `TextBoxFor(m => m[5].UserName)` MVC will generate `<input type=text name="[5].UserName>`. So you have to *accept* in your controller *multiple* names too.

Change your action signature to:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(LogonViewModel[] lvms)
```

(and move your `submit` out of your `for`, it will submit entire form anyway)

Comment: [HttpPost] public ActionResult Index(sting[] firstname) { LogonViewModel lv = new LogonViewModel(); return View(); }. It passing null If I do in this way.

Comment: Because your view produces `POST` with array of `LogonViewModel`, not array of `string`.